# Expose ASP.NET Core Prometheus metrics on another port

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, prometheus, asp.net-core-3.1, prometheus-net

I'm setting up a Prometheus exporter for my ASP.NET Core 3.1 app.

I've imported

`<PackageReference Include="prometheus-net.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.1" />`

And this is what I have configured:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseHttpMetrics();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapMetrics();
    });
}
```

This will expose the metrics endpoint on the same port as the rest of the ASP.NET Core application, for example: `my.api.com:80/metrics`.

What do I need to do to expose the `/metrics` endpoint on another port? I would like to have my API running on port 80, and the `/metrics` endpoint on port 9102.

Can't really find any docs about that.

**Edit**

I'm deploying this into Kubernetes

Comment: The routing of the entire project is a whole, and a single routing cannot be changed. You can configure routing relay in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up doing like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseMetricServer(9102);

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseHttpMetrics();

    ...

}
```

And then for my Kubernetes `Deployment` I had to add both port 80 and 9102 to `containerPort`s under `ports`.

Additionally I had to set the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable to `http://+:80;http://+:9102`

That way, `/metrics` is only exposed on port 9102. (However the rest of my API is exposed on both port 80 and 9102).

Comment: I tried to make that work, but couldn't access the data on that port. After looking at the current sample app "Sample.Web.DifferentPort", I found something slightly different. If I used services.AddMetricServer( options => options.Port=9102); then it worked. Here's the URL to the sample code: https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net/blob/master/Sample.Web.DifferentPort/Program.cs